# ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError: table "users" has no column named "monkey"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, fixtures

Hi I just started coding with rails, following Michael Hartl tutorial, I got this error while writing test for my app, my fixture on `test/fixtures/users.yml` is:

```
# Read about fixtures at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html

marwane:
  name: Marwane Chahoud
  email: marwane.chahoud@gmail.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>

  monkey:
  name: Sterling Archer
  email: sterling.archer@strange.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

and my db schema is: `db/migrate/xxxxxx_create_users.rb` :

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I am using ruby version : `ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [i386-mingw32]`
and rails version : `Rails 4.2.6`

Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError: table “users” has no column named
>   “monkey”

I believe its due to the *indentation problem*. *YAML files are strict in indenting*. It should be

```
marwane:
  name: Marwane Chahoud
  email: marwane.chahoud@gmail.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>

monkey:
  name: Sterling Archer
  email: sterling.archer@strange.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

Since the *key* `monkey:` is *indented wrongly*, it is treated as *attribute*,so is the error.